# How do I add a value to a parameter in an init function in python

Tags: python, function, parameters, constructor, init

Would it work if I added these values in this way or do I need to add double quotes to the values like "ENGR", "ARTS", ...etc"? Also am I supposed to use curly brackets or square brackets?

```
def __init__(self, d_code = {ENGR, ARTS, CHHS}, d_name = {Engineering, Art, College of Health and Human Services}
```

Comment: Of course you can do that.  Just beware that if you use a mutable type as a default value, you must take care not to modify it, since any such change will affect subsequent calls.  This holds for both ordinary functions and methods.

Comment: If `ENGR` is a defined constant (that is, you have `ENGR = 3` somewhere), then it will work.  If those are just strings, as I suspect they are, then of course they have to be in quotes.  Those are lists, so they would be in square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write it like this:

```
class Classes:
    def __init__(self, d_code = ["ENGR", "ARTS", "CHHS"], d_name = ["Engineering", "Art", "College of Health and Human Services"]):
        self.codes = d_code
        self.names = d_name
```

However, Tom pointed out a very nasty gotcha that can occur with situations like this.  If you modify `self.codes`, that modifies the list object, and will affect future instances of the object.  Thus, code like that is sometimes written this way:

```
class Classes:
    def __init__(self, d_code = None, d_name = None):
        self.codes = d_code or ["ENGR", "ARTS", "CHHS"]
        self.names = d_name or ["Engineering", "Art", "College of Health and Human Services"]
```